# $f$ bijective and analytic in a disk $D$ implies $f(\text{bd}(D)) = \text{bd}(D)$

Tags: complex-analysis

to be more specific, $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $\text{bd}(D)$ is the boundary of $D$.

In my attempted proof, I used the maximum modulus principle to say that both $|f|$ and $|f^{-1}|$ hit their maximum values in $\text{bd}(D)$. Then I feel that the fact that $f$ is bijective would imply that $f(\text{bd}(D)) = \text{bd}(D)$, but I can't justify it well enough.

Comment: Are we assuming that $f$ is defined on an open set including the closed unit disk?

Comment: ... or at least continuous on the closed unit disk?

Comment: It is continuous and analytic.

Comment: (on the unit disk.)

Comment: analytic in the open disk and continuous on the boundary?